# In Nodejs, why are recursive and non-recursive object traversal almost the same in this case

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, recursion, v8

The following is my code for comparison. I am doing some optimization for my project and found the non-recursive solution has no advantage over the recursive one, which is against my intuition: the performance is almost linearly the same.

I'm wondering if this case is the specific one or there are some details about the v8 engine I don't know.

EDITED:

I have put the generation of random object outside the loop, they are still almost linearly the same.

```
"use restrict";

if (!Array.prototype.fill) {
    Array.prototype.fill = function(content) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            this[i] = content;
        }
    };
}

var getClassName = (function () {

    var NULL_OBJECT = {};

    return function(obj) {
        return NULL_OBJECT.toString.apply(obj).slice(8, -1);
    }
})();

var Stack = function(opts) {
    opts = opts || {};
    var capacity = opts.capacity;
    if (!capacity) {
        capacity = 64;
    }
    this.capacity = capacity;
    this.list = new Array(this.capacity);
    this.cursor = 0;
};

Stack.prototype.__doubleTheSize = function() {
    this.list = this.list.concat(new Array(this.capacity));
    this.capacity = this.capacity * 2;
};

Stack.prototype.push = function(obj) {
    if (this.cursor == this.capacity - 1) {
        this.__doubleTheSize();
    }
    this.list[this.cursor] = obj;
    this.cursor += 1;
};

Stack.prototype.clear = function() {
    this.cursor = 0;
    this.list.fill(undefined);
};

Stack.prototype.pop = function() {
    if (this.cursor == 0) {
        throw new Error('Stack is empty, pop is illegal.');
    }
    var val = this.list[this.cursor - 1];
    this.list[this.cursor - 1] = undefined;
    this.cursor -= 1;
    return val;
};

function traverseRecursivly(obj, funcVisit) {

    var className = getClassName(obj);
    funcVisit(obj);
    if (className != 'Object' && className != 'Array') {
        return;
    }
    for (var i in obj) {
        traverseRecursivly(obj[i], funcVisit);
    }
}

var traverseNonRecursivly = (function() {

    var stack = new Stack({
        capacity: 1024
    });

    return function(obj, funcVisit) {

        var __obj = obj;
        stack.push(__obj);
        while (stack.cursor > 0) {
            __obj = stack.pop();
            var className = getClassName(__obj);
            funcVisit(__obj);
            if (className != 'Object' && className != 'Array') {
                continue;
            }
            for (var i in __obj) {
                stack.push(__obj[i]);
            }
        }
    };
})();

var genRandomTreeObject = (function() {

    var stack = new Stack();

    return function(size) {

        var head = {
            value: 0
        };
        stack.push(head);

        for (var i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
            var node = {
                value: i
            };

            var parent = stack.list[Math.floor(Math.random() * stack.cursor)];
            parent[i] = node;
            stack.push(node);
        }

        stack.clear();
        return head;
    }

})();

var randomObject = genRandomTreeObject(1024);

console.time('recursive');
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    var sum = 0;
    traverseNonRecursivly(randomObject, function(o) {
        if (o.value) {
            sum += o.value;
        }
    })
}
console.log(sum);
console.timeEnd('recursive');

console.time('non-recursive');
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    var sum = 0;
    traverseRecursivly(randomObject, function(o) {
        if (o.value) {
            sum += o.value;
        }
    })
}
console.log(sum);
console.timeEnd('non-recursive');
```

Comment: you are measuring quite a bit with those timings, might it be that `genRandomTree * 1000`  takes much of the time, shadowing the `traverse*` timings ?

Comment: Your `traverseNonRecursivly` function will get real problems if it is called again on a different object from within the `funcVisit`. You should create a new `Stack` for each invokation.

Comment: @birdspider I have put the generation of random object outside the loop, I seems that the difference is still almost linearly the same.

Comment: I can't see why you'd expect the non-recursive solution to be faster. It just reimplements in your own code what the recursive call does. To me, the wonder is why it isn't *slower*. (And it probably would be, if V8 had tail call recursion, which it will soon...) You've just traded calling the function itself with calling `push` and `pop`.

Comment: @Bergi Yes u r right. I think editing the while loop in traverseNonRecursivly can solve the problem while reusing the same stack.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Tail recursion doesn't help here. I guess the non-recursive solution could be faster because it avoids costly function calls, but this overengineered `Stack` implementation seems to negate any of the effort.

Comment: @Bergi: (Re TCO) No, I suppose not, looking at what it's doing. In any case, a non-recursive solution that requires extra function calls isn't likely to compete well with a recursive solution (barring running out of stack, which I don't see above), as they just replace the call being avoided.

Comment: Did you profile your benchmark? My guess is most of the execution time might be spent in the for-in constructs or such, so even if the non-recursive traversal is a win, it's very little compared to the time spent in, say, property lookup.

Comment: @VladislavIvanishin Yes, a more detailed profiling is very needed.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes I think your thoughts make great sense. If I commenting the funcVisit in both solutions, the non-recursive one become slightly better than the recursive one (If not, the result is the reverse). And as VladislavIvanishin said, Maybe in my test case, property lookup take major time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct (see comments to the question). I did the profiling and it reveals that only 4% of the time is spent in `traverse[Non]Recursivly()` while more than 83% is spent in C++ runtime namely in `v8::internal::JSObject::GetOwnElementKeys()` (>57%).

```
[JavaScript]:
ticks  total  nonlib   name
  98    4.0%    4.0%  LazyCompile: ~traverseRecursivly

  ... 

[C++]:
ticks  total  nonlib   name
 1399   57.6%   57.7%  v8::internal::JSObject::GetOwnElementKeys(...)

  ...

[Summary]:
  ticks  total  nonlib   name
   389   16.0%   16.0%  JavaScript
  2037   83.8%   84.0%  C++
    11    0.5%    0.5%  GC
     4    0.2%          Shared libraries

[C++ entry points]:
  ticks    cpp   total   name
  1665   82.4%   68.5%  v8::internal::Runtime_GetPropertyNamesFast(...)
   207   10.2%    8.5%  v8::internal::Runtime_SubStringRT(...)
  ...
```

[image: black color for code kind in execution means runtime]

Comment: Great answer. If possible, can you share how can I redo your profiling.

Comment: @jo32, sure thing. Assuming you are on linux and have pure v8 built from source: `$D8_PATH/d8 --prof --log_timer_events source.js`, then `$D8_PATH/../../tools/linux-tick-processor` for detailed text statistics (on linux), and/or `$D8_PATH/../../tools/plot-timer-events v8.log` for the plot (you'll need gnuplot). See http://www.chromium.org/developers/creating-v8-profiling-timeline-plots for more info and to gain some understanding on how to read the plots. You might want to add `--noprof_browser_mode` to the first command (I don't really know).